# Data structure for heterogeneous csv using python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am dealing with a peculiar csv file containing about 900 rows

```
0.0165824,+,ESI,ms1,-,line,40.0000-700.0000,663,35.2072 12,37.7808 11,38.0004 17,39.1216 18,39.1755 11,40.0806 12,41.4810 11,42.0517 19
```

The values are separated by commas "`,`". However, starting from the 9th column onward the file contains tuple values, which I am actually interested in. I wanted to use `pandas` for this job. As the number of columns is not equal for the different rows I used this approach:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open('test.csv') as fb:
    reader = csv.reader(fb)
    df = pd.DataFrame().from_records(reader)
```

This yields a data frame containing the tuples as strings. From there on, I first planed to create either a multiple index data frame using the first column as an the outer index and an inner index for each of the tuple values (9th column onward). Or as an alternative multiple data frames contained in a dictionary using the first column as the key.

Currently, I am using this code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

raw_data = 'test.csv'

result = {}
lower_mass = 200
upper_mass = 300

with open(raw_data, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        mz = []
        i = []
        key = float(row[0])
        data = row[8:]
        for d in data:
            tup = d.split(" ")
            mass = float(tup[0])
            intens = float(tup[1])
            if (mass > lower_mass) & (mass < upper_mass):
                mz.append(float(tup[0]))
                i.append(float(tup[1]))
        result[key] = {"mz": mz, "I": i}
```

This generates a dictionary containing two lists for the values `mz` and `I` using the first column as the key and for clarity also dropping some columns I do not want to store (1-7). I also apply a filter to shrink the data (lower_mass and upper_mass). These operations would have been carried out on the data frame instead.

I am not happy, because I lose the ability for data manipulation in a vectorized manner. Finally, the data should be used to find some `mz` values within the different keys.

Is there a better/faster solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do, if not let me know and I'll edit my answer.

The way I approached this is to use the [melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) and [str.split](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) functions in pandas. The melt will transform "wide" data to "long" data which will allow you to split the tuples and finally filter your data.

Using this CSV file, which has rows with different widths and all relevant data starting at column 8.

```
0.0165824,+,ESI,ms1,-,line,40.0000-700.0000,663,35.2072 12,37.7808 11,38.0004 17,39.1216 18,39.1755 11,40.0806 12,41.4810 11,42.0517 19
0.0165825,+,ESI,ms1,-,line,40.0000-700.0000,663,35.2072 12,37.7808 11,38.0004 17,39.1216 18,39.1755 11,40.0806 12,41.4810 11,42.0517 19,40.0806 12,41.4810 11,42.0517 19
0.0165826,+,ESI,ms1,-,line,40.0000-700.0000,663,35.2072 12,37.7808 11,38.0004 17,39.1216 18,39.1755 11
```

the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('s.csv', header=None, names=np.arange(19)) # Read in CSV, use names to handle different CSV row widths
df = df.drop(np.arange(1,8), axis="columns") # Drop columns 1:7
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=[0], value_vars=np.arange(8, df.shape[1])) # Melt data columns 8:N

# df.head()
#   0           variable    value
# 0 0.016582    8           35.2072 12
# 1 0.016583    8           35.2072 12
# 2 0.016583    8           35.2072 12
# 3 0.016582    9           37.7808 11
# 4 0.016583    9           37.7808 1

df[['mass','I']] = df.value.str.split(" ", expand=True).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') # Split value column and apply change from string to numeric datatype; assign split to mass and I columns
df = df.rename(columns={0: "key", 'variable':'csv_column'}).drop('value', axis='columns') # Rename column zero to key and drop string column

# df.head()
#   key         csv_column  mass    I
#0  0.016582    8           35.2072 12
#1  0.016583    8           35.2072 12
#2  0.016583    8           35.2072 12
#3  0.016582    9           37.7808 11
#4  0.016583    9           37.7808 11
```

Now you can use pandas to filter and sort. Note that "blank" values from CSV will translate to `NaN` in pandas; this isn't shown in the `df.head()` output above. This is a consequence of using `errors='coerce'` in the `pd.to_numeric` function.

Comment: Thank you for the effort! @Josh. Pandas will not read in the file due to the different length of columns. A work around would be the find the maximum number of columns prior to reading in the file and add the `name` attribute. However, the residual code works fine.

Comment: Hey @Fourier, I've updated my answer using the names parameter, you can also just provide an array to `names` with a width you know will be wider than your data and then just filter the `NaNs` from your dataframe.